# Configuring SSH for localhost

Tags: ssh, permissions

I'm following a guide to set up SSH for localhost.
After I created the private/public pair of keys, it told me to change the permission of file that contains the key, by doing

```
chmod 0600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

My question is: why do I have to change the permissions of this file ?
I search on the web but I didn't find anything.

Comment: It is for security reason so that no process running in another users security context can read, or worse modify this file.

Comment: So the file ~/.ssh/authorized_keys is in the host ?

Comment: Yes. It contains the public keys of users allowed to access this host.

Answer (score 2):

This kind of requirement is for security-reasons only.

If you allow access to this file to `others` or `group` (by `UNIX` permissions meaning) with writing and reading, there are two security problems:

- With write permission, everyone (or group member accordingly) will be able to write his own public key there, so authenticate as user who owns `~` directory.
- With read permissions, everyone (or group member accordingly) will be able to read authorized public keys, so information leak.

References:

- [Securing OpenSSH | CentOS Wiki](https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/Network/SecuringSSH)
- [OpenSSH security | Linux Audit](https://linux-audit.com/audit-and-harden-your-ssh-configuration/)

Comment: So the file ~/.ssh/authorized_keys is in the host ?